# DB Exception Cannot Roll Back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

I get the `XML` parsing error,when i pass `&` symbols, so now i pass '&' as '&', But now i got the following `Execption`

`DB Exception Cannot roll back CANDI_INSERT. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.`
Send the solution to pass `&` through `XML` to save in database. Thanks in advance...